# What does "strobe" do for this shift register?

Tags: shift-register

I would like to know what 'strobe' pin does for HV5812 shift register, because I do see it in the time graph[image]

But the datasheet does not elaborate on its function, it only says 'strobe'
[image]

Is this pin crucial for the functioning of this shift register? What does it do? I have worked with 74HC595, but I see this for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strobe input is the signal that latches the 20-bits in parallel from the shift register to the output (after you've shifted in what you want).

[image]

It's similar to RCLK on the 74HC595.

Comment: Now that you showed me, I wonder how I did not see this!

Comment: @user43648 The timing diagram could have showed a previous shift clock pulse and made it more clear what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

Once you shift data into the shift register you need to toggle the strobe line to transfer the data into the latch (and onto the outputs). This lets you load data into the device without affecting the output state, and then change all outputs at the same time.