# strobe/enable output pins role in MC14094B

Tags: shift-register, enable

I would like to ask about the "strobe" pin and "enable output" pin in MC14094B (shift register)
what does these pins exactly means? what storbe pin do? what is it's role ?
i would be glad for good explaining
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

**Strobe pin** :

> Once you shift data into the shift register you need to toggle the strobe line to transfer the data into the latch and onto the outputs. This lets you load data into the device without affecting the output state, and then change all outputs at the same time.

<sub>Originally from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/356592/101852) on the question "[What does “strobe” do for this shift register?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356586/what-does-strobe-do-for-this-shift-register)"</sub>

**Output Enable** : You can consider this pin as switch means when ever it is "0" there is no effect on output side and you have to put it "1" to make it functional

Comment: Abhishek bhatia - Hi, As required by [this site rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), when you include something in an answer (e.g. photo, image or text) which isn't your own original work, you must properly reference (cite) it. Plagiarism is not accepted here. Since (at least half of) the answer text was copied from from somewhere else, I added the required link back to the original web page. Do you need to reference a source for the other text? I recommend you read the [tour] and [help] to see more about the site rules and philosophy. Thanks :-)